# Setting up Ruby on rails web application on Linode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, setup-deployment, vps, linode

I am an absolute newbie to web development and ruby on rails.  I am planing to deploy a ror application on the Linode 512 plan.  My website would be basically a forum that allows users to upload photos using Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.

Which OS should I use? What are their difference? (Ubuntu / Debian / CentOS / Fedora)

Should I use Apache or Nginx?  What are their difference?

Should I use PostgreSQL, MySQL, MongoDB or any other kinds of DB provided on Linode?  What are their difference?

My target audience would come from China which means I can't use Amazon S3.  Should I let the users upload the photos to the Linode server?

Is there any step-by-step beginner‘s guide for this issue?

Thx

Comment: I found the Linode documentation itself to be a great guide: http://library.linode.com/

Comment: If you are this new to system administration, you might not want to set up a production machine facing the internet! The differences between the Linuxes and the web servers come down to preference really, choose any (I use Debian & Nginx). PostgreSQL and MySQL are used as traditional relational databases. Use them if you know SQL. MongoDB is a NoSQL database. Don't use it if you don't already know what that means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, I think you are worrying too much. If you are a newbie, just follow the popular choice for a start, then change, modify, scale as you go. As your skills mature, you will know what best suites you.

Below are some choices that will be easier for you:

1. Which OS should I use? What are their difference? **Ubuntu**
2. Should I use Apache or Nginx? What are their difference? **Apache. If it is a small website, it doesn't matter for now.**
3. Should I use PostgreSQL, MySQL, MongoDB or any other kinds of DB provided on Linode? What are their difference? **MySQL. MongoDB is a NoSQL database, may not be for you for the moment.**
4. My target audience would come from China which means I can't use Amazon S3. Should I let the users upload the photos to the Linode server? **Upload to Linode for now. Don't scale it prematurely.**
5. Is there any step-by-step beginner‘s guide for this issue? **Ryan's RailsCasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/373-zero-downtime-deployment and http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps, they are must-watch, but not free.**

For all these setup, [Linode's tutorial](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.10-maverick) is good for a start. You should look at @Stefan answer too.

You should also try to deploy to [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) just to get a feel of it. [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) is good for you to learn up from development to deployment.

Answer (score 5):

There are several dedicated Rails setup guides on Linode:

**Apache and Passenger:**

- [Ruby on Rails with Apache on Debian 6 (Squeeze)](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/debian-6-squeeze)
- [Ruby on Rails with Apache on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid)](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.04-lucid)
- [Ruby on Rails with Apache on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick)](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-apache/ubuntu-10.10-maverick)

**nginx and Passenger:**

- [Ruby on Rails with Nginx on Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid)](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/ubuntu-10.04-lucid)
- [Ruby on Rails with Nginx on Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick)](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/ubuntu-10.10-maverick)
- [Ruby on Rails with Nginx on Debian 5 (Lenny)](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/debian-5-lenny)
- [Ruby on Rails with Nginx on CentOS 5](http://library.linode.com/frameworks/ruby-on-rails-nginx/centos-5)

Answer (score 1):

As we have many linode deployment for rails apps my recommendation would be:

```
ubuntu/centos + mysql/postgres + nginx + passenger
```

If your application is going to have huge fb inout operations then you can `mongodb` as choice